# What is b flops in tfprof (tensorflow profiler) model analysis report?

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, flops

Eg:

```
_TFProfRoot (--/3163.86b flops)
InceptionResnetV2/InceptionResnetV2/Mixed_6a/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/convolution (173.41b/173.41b flops)
```

What does `b flops` mean?
I guess `m flops` means `mega flops`. But, what does `'b' flops` mean?
Apparently, `b flops` is bigger than `m flops` since I know that model analysis report prints flops values in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

It means billions :)

quoted from source:
"return strings::Printf("%.2fb", n / 1000000000.0);"